# From a point-wise to a linear piece-wise definition

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Consider the following definition:
$$f(x, \alpha) = \left\{\begin{array}{cl}A(x) & \alpha = 0\\ B(x) & \alpha = 0.5 \\ C(x) & \alpha=1 \end{array}\right.$$

where we always have $A(x) < B(x) < C(x)$

I would like to build function $g(x,\alpha)$ that is **piecewise linear**, that is:

- Linear between $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ for values of $\alpha \in [0, 0.5]$
- Linear between $B(x)$ and $C(x)$ for values of $\alpha \in [0.5, 1]$

How can I can come up with an algebraic expression for $g(x,\alpha)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use
$$
(1-\lambda) x_1 + \lambda x_2
$$

with $\lambda \in [0, 1]$ to linear interpolate between $x_1$ and $x_2$.

This might lead to

\begin{align}
g_1(x, \alpha) &= (1-\lambda_1) A(x) + \lambda_1 B(x) \\
g_2(x, \alpha) &= (1-\lambda_2) B(x) + \lambda_2 C(x) \\
\end{align}

The rest is mapping from $\alpha\in [0,1/2]$ to $\lambda_1\in [0,1]$ and
$\alpha\in [1/2,1]$ to $\lambda_2\in [0,1]$:
$$
\lambda_1 =  2 \alpha
\quad
\lambda_2 = 2 (\alpha - 1/2) = 2 \alpha - 1
$$
which gives
\begin{align}
g_1(x, \alpha) &= (1-2\alpha) A(x) + 2\alpha B(x) \\
g_2(x, \alpha) &= (2-2\alpha) B(x) + (2\alpha - 1) C(x) \\
\end{align}

Finally we need to piece both $g_1$ and $g_2$ together into one function $g$.

For the case switch we need the unit step function (Heaviside function)
$$
H(x) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
0 & \mbox{for } x < 0 \\
1 & \mbox{for } x \ge 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
which would be applied as this:
$$
g(x, \alpha) = 
\left(1- H\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right) g_1(x,\alpha) + 
H\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\right) g_2(x, \alpha) \quad (*)
$$

As an alternative to $H$ we could use the signum function
$$
\mbox{sgn}(x) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
-1 & \mbox{for } x < 0 \\
0  & \mbox{for } x = 0 \\
1  & \mbox{for } x > 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

and use it to define
$$
h(x) = \frac{\mbox{sgn}(x) + 1}{2}
=
\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
0   & \mbox{for } x < 0 \\
1/2 & \mbox{for } x = 0 \\
1   & \mbox{for } x > 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
It would work with equation $(*)$ as well, using the mean of $g_1$ and $g_2$ at $\alpha = 1/2$ which happens to be $B(x)$.

If there is no signum function available one could use $\tilde{h}(x)=\tanh(c x)$ with a large positive constant $c$ as an approximation.

Comment: This is great. Thanks! My only question left, how did you get the equations $\lambda_1 =2\alpha$ and $\lambda_2 = 2 (\alpha - 1/2) = 2 \alpha - 1$ from the translation?

Comment: Just mapping $\alpha:[0,0.5]\to  [0,1]$ for $\lambda_1$ and for the second case mapping  $\alpha:[0.5,1] \to [0,1]$ for $\lambda_2$

Comment: @user815423426 I added this to the answer.